# How to get the href value out of a list of webelements with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, href, getattribute

I want to get the link attribute from the below list of elements, Its returning null when executing

```
<div class="ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content">
    <div class="ui-lib-margin-b_md ui-lib-margin-t_md totalResultsText">
        <p class="totalResultsText">Showing 1-10 of 316 results</p>
    </div>
    <div class="" style="">
        <div class="ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy">
            <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item">
                <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content">
                    <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header">
                        <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type">
                            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <title></title>
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle>
                            </svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div>
                    </div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Collection and Transfer of Green Waste from Residential Areas" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/environmentagriculture/Waste-Management/WasteCollectionandTransportation/RequestforCollectionandTransferofGreenWastefromResidentialAreas"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Collection and Transfer of Green Waste from Residential Areas</h4></a>
                    <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Through this service, you can request the collection and transfer of green wastes from residential areas.</div>
                    <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags">
                        <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Waste Management Center</span></div>
                        <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Expat</span></div>
                        <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Visitor</span></div>
                        <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div>
                    </div>
```

Code trials:

```
List<WebElement> FirstFive = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div")).stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(FirstFive.size());
for (WebElement webElement : FirstFive){
    String link = webElement.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(link);
}
```

I need to store the value in a variable.

Comment: Your Xpath expression has `//` about 40 characters in (I didn't count), where it should have `/`.   Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link attribute are basically the value of ***href*** attributes and to extract those you can use the following solution:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div//a")).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("href")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```